# Chrome extension > contextMenus Api > can not add onclick handler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension. Currently I am about to create context menu for my extension, which will do something when I click on it. So, following
google documentation i create parent.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "bla", id: "parent"});
```

Then I create child and try to add `onclick` handler to it.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "bla bla", 
  parentId: "parent",
  id: "child",
  onclick : function() { alert("bla bla bla") }
});
```

So, its works fine without onclick, and not works all at when onclick here.

Comment: Does your manifest have `"background": {"persistent": false},`?

Comment: Yes i have such line in my manifest.

Answer (score 3):

Event based background pages (persistent=false) have to use `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked` listeners.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({...});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    alert("bla bla bla");
});
```

Comment: How does one get information about the click this way? Is that a hole in the API or an error in the docs?

Comment: According to the [sample extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#context-menus-sample-(with-event-page)) it takes the same parameters as the onclick method you were trying to use.