# contextMenu onclick event not firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

-- SOLVED [see comments section] --

I'm having an issue with `contextMenu` `onclick` event.

When i try to create the menu dynamically from JSON that I request from an external API. The `onclick` event doesn't fire only after I reload the extension and has the `contextMenu` already created.

```
var data = firstext.db.getJSON("list");
for ( list in data ) {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": list.name, "contexts": ["all"], "onclick": function(data) { console.log('clicked: ' + list.id);}});
}
```

Manifest:

```
{
"version": "0.1.3",
"manifest_version": 2,
"default_locale": "en",
"name": "__MSG_appName__",
"description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
"icons" : {
    "16" : "assets/images/on16.png",
    "24" : "assets/images/on24.png",
    "48" : "assets/images/on48.png",
    "128" : "assets/images/on.png"
},
"browser_action" : {
    "default_popup" : "popup.html",
    "default_icon" : "assets/images/off24.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["assets/js/library.js", "assets/js/background.js"]
},
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
]}
```

Comment: Please include your manifest, specifically, the `background` key.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I added the manifest content

Comment: Is the code you quote in the popup by any chance?

Comment: In background.js i have this: 
firstext.initBackground();  and in firstext.initBackground i have the code above and that is in library.js

Comment: So you're saying that the menu items are created, but there is no reaction on click? And what happens after a reload?

Comment: When i make the request from API the contextMenu gets created and i store the json in localstorage and the onclick event doesn't work. It works only after i refresh the page in chrome://extensions because the data remains in localstorage and the menu gets created at runtime

Comment: I think i cracked it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711990/chrome-extension-contextmenus-api-can-not-add-onclick-handler?rq=1. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked .

Comment: That's why I asked for your manifest. Your background page is not an event page, so that question does not immediately apply. Though making it work through the listener is probably a good idea anyway.